# Литература по корутинам ТС

Tags: c++, асинхронность, coroutine, c++20

Подскажите, существует ли на сегодняшний день какая-нибудь полноценная литература по тем самым корутинам, которых еще пока нет в STL, и которые пока вроде как заменяет либа [cppcoro](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro)? Или только посты на Хабре читать остается? Не нашёл нигде ни одной книги или полноценного гайда какого-нибудь, только пару статей на Хабре от Яндекса и издательства Питер =(

Comment: ¿А почитать документацию и / или стандарт - не вариант?

Comment: @user7860670, сразу код компилчтора лучше)) Что тут поймешь из этого? http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4680.pdf

Comment: финальную версию стандарта опубликовали __буквально__ только в этом месяце... ещё даже не выпущены версии компиляторов с полноценной поддержкой корутин... и это при том, что с++20 по количеству изменений в языке сравним с с++11... в общем за приличной литературой приходи через года 2—3...

Comment: Запрос в гугл `coroutines in programming paradigms` выдает довольно много материала.

Comment: Тоже [может быть интересно](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html)

Comment: А это вообще историческая (1979 года) книжка ["COROUTINES: A PROGRAIÍMING METIIODOLOGY A LANGUAGE DESIGN AND IMPLEMENTATION"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwius6uA-t_tAhWjtIsKHWjwDcQ4HhAWMAN6BAgGEAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdigital.library.adelaide.edu.au%2Fdspace%2Fbitstream%2F2440%2F21027%2F2%2F02whole.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2WgmbQ1-vC59WNJBRq1MF9)